# Исключительные ситуации c++

Tags: c++

Есть задание [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
using namespace std;

float y;

float funct(float x)
{
    try
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            throw "x равен 0"; 
        }
        else
        {
            y = 1 / pow(pow(x, 2), 1 / 3);
        }
    }
    catch (const char *report)
    {
        cout << " " << report << " " << "x = " << x;
    }
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    for (float i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << " " << "f = " << funct(i) << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Всегда возвращает 1, не могу понять в чем проблема. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Целочисленное деление - `1 / 3` - это просто 0. Пишите `1. / 3`...

Comment: И еще - ну зачем эти сложности? ` y = 1 / pow(pow(x, 2), 1 / 3);`? Пишите `y=pow(x*x,-1./3);` - так и от знака избавитесь, и деление не нужно :)